# Transferring json data between Android client and C# server

Tags: java, c#, json, architecture, data-transfer

I am passing the data between Server (C# .Net 4.6.1) and Client (Android App SDK ver. >= 9)

I use JSON to get text representation of custom class instances and send them over network.

There is *set of classes*, instances of which I'm able to send. Each class implements interface:

```
public interface IJsonData
{
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    int MinimalClientVersion { get; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    int Constructor { get; }
}
```

Example of class from *set*:

```
[DataContract]
public class JsonDataChatMessage : IJsonData
{
    #region IJsonData implemetation
    //goes here
    #endregion

    [DataMember]
    public string SenderName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

ServerJsonMessage's Creator takes instance of any class that implements interface and fills his fields:

```
[DataContract]
public class ServerJsonMessage
{
    [DataMember]
    public int MinimalClientVersion { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int Constructor { get; set; } //Numeric id of Data

    [DataMember]
    public dynamic Data { get; set; } //OVER HERE!

    private ServerJsonMessage()
    {
        //hide constructor
    }

    public static ServerJsonMessage Create(IJsonData jsonData)
    {
            return serverJsonMessage = new ServerJsonMessage
            {
                MinimalClientVersion = jsonData.MinimalClientVersion,
                Constructor = jsonData.Constructor,
                //Option 1
                //Data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonData)
                //Option 2
                Data = jsonData
            };
    }

    public string ToJson()
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
    }
}
```

The question is:

### What is the best option to fill Data field? Should it be String or Object or IJsonData or any other?

It may look like there is nothing to worry about, but the algorythm of receiving such messages on client looks like this:

1. Receiving and parsing JSON representation of ServerJsonMessage
2. Later checking value of getConstructor() to find out class of ServerJsonMessage.Data and parse it.

.

```
ServerJsonMessage serverJsonMessage = ServerJsonMessage.parse(textFromServer);
if(serverJsonMessage.getConstructor() == 1234){
    JsonDataChatMessage jsonDataChatMessage 
        = JsonDataChatMessage.parse(serverJsonMessage.getData())
                //work
}
```

Client's ServerJsonMessage class looks like this:

```
public class ServerJsonMessage {
    private int MinimalClientVersion;
    private int Constructor;
    //option1
    //private String Data; 
    //option2
    private Object Data;

    public static ServerJsonMessage parse(String json)
        throws Exception {
        ServerJsonMessage serverJsonMessage = new Gson().fromJson(json, ServerJsonMessage.class);
        return serverJsonMessage;
    }
}
```

### If I use option 1:

Parsing of JsonDataChatMessage looks nice:

```
JsonDataChatMessage msg = JsonDataChatMessage.parse(serverJsonMessage.getData());
```

But JSON's Data field as string itself looks ugly:

```
{
"MinimalClientVersion": 0,
"Constructor": 1234,
"Data": "[{\"Id\":\"f3c1d07d-b1b1-4d09-a91e-17b7b348b06c\",\"IdUser\":null,\"Route\":[{\"CName\":null,\"Code\":2,\"Name\":null,\"Type\":\"fdf\",\"SName\":\"hhh\",\"Other\":null,\"Increase\":0.0,\"GeoPoint\":null},{\"CName\":null,\"Code\":14, ... }]"
}
```

Another disadvantage of this approach is that i can't define in advance is there an array or a single object inside "Data"

### If I use option 2:

Parsing of JsonDataChatMessage requires converting Data into String at first that causes unnecessary performance loss

```
String string = new Gson().toJson(serverJsonMessage.getData())
JsonDataChatMessage msg = JsonDataChatMessage.parse(string);
```

because

```
//this line throws exception
JsonDataChatMessage jsonDataChatMessage = (JsonDataChatMessage)serverJsonMessage.getData();
```

What is the best way of sending my data? Which option should I choose or how do I need to change the architecture of my system?

Comment: why java tagging? Seems like it is completely C# .Net question.

Comment: @RBT Andriod app written on Java